# Using Azure Search Indexer on Azure Table JSON field

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am using Microsoft Azure Search on an Azure Table.  One of the columns in the table is JSON data (not an array).  What is the best way to extract discrete fields from that column during indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use field mappings to map the property names from the table to the field names in your search index. Use [FieldMappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.indexer.fieldmappings?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_Indexer_FieldMappings) property to Get or Set defined mappings between fields in the data source and corresponding target fields in the index.

Comment: The Field mapping functions don't include one for JSON objects, just Base64, Token extraction, URLs, and JSON Arrays to String collections.

Comment: Can you get them attributes as separate columns in table, by deflating the object and store them separately.